# MVC Create URL Back to Original Page on Timeout

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my `Controller` I have a function which helps me check for any `Session` timeouts, this works fine and it directs the users to an error page.  Unfortunately from here I really just have the option to go back to the homepage, what I would like is to create the functionality to take them back to the previous page.

Each page will have a form of ID attached in the query string (this isn't always called ID, but it is always a unique number to identify the object.

What I need is to try and get this ID (always the first parameter / key) and use this as a basis to create the `ActionLink` on the view.  I can get the `RawUrl` using the `ActionExecutedContext` which contains the requesting raw URL, but I'm unsure how to actuall make this useful.

The following is the code which executes after my Action, it validates if the user has timed out and moves them to an error page.  The ErrorId of -1001 is just to identify that this is a timeout.  What I need is an ID, similar to what I can kind of see in the `RawUrl` property, which I can then use as part of the `RedirectToAction` to take the user back to the original page.

```
protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session != null)
{
if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session.IsNewSession)
{
string cookie = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Cookie"];
if ((cookie != null) && (cookie.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId") >= 0))
{
filterContext.Result = RedirectToAction("Error", new { errorId = -1001, errorMessage ="Your session has timed out.Please restart the application or click 'Home' below."});
return;
}
}
base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... and it directs the users to an error page.

When making this redirect pass as query string parameter a `ReturnUrl`. This parameter will be the current request url.

Then inside the error page you will be able to use this ReturnUrl query string parameter to build an anchor or a form pointing to the initially requested resource. For example:

```
<a href="@Request["ReturnUrl"]">Go back</a>
```

Comment: Sorry not sure I follow?  I'm doing the RedirectToAction from inside an overriden method called after the controller action, I don't see how I can pass any additional parameters to it?

Comment: The `RedirectToAction` method has multiple overloads. The one that takes an `object` is what you are looking for. You could pass additional query string parameters as an anonymous object: `RedirectToAction("SomeAction", new { ReturnUrl = "..." })`

Comment: Yeah I can do that, but I don't have is the ID of the page that the user has just been on.  I shall add the code to the original question.

Comment: In order to retrieve the current url just use the `HttpContext.Request.Url` property.

Comment: The last comment (containing `HttpContext.Request.Url`) helped.